# LINQ issue on joining table multiple times

Tags: sql, join

I have inherited a schema which I need to get some sql working on. It is to show a products variation such as colour and size variants of jumper. The schema has 1 table for products :

TABLE tbl_Product

```
[ProductID] [int],
[Quantity] [int],
[Title] [nvarchar](500),
[Description] [varchar](max),
[Price] [money]
```

etc...

**another table as a linking table for the variations**

TABLE tbl_ProductVariation

```
[ProductVariationID] [int],
[ProductID] [int] ,
[VariationID] [int]
```

**and the variation table**

TABLE tbl_Variation

```
[VariationID] [int],
[VariationTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[USTitle] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[UKTitle] [nvarchar](150) NULL
```

so the variation value can contain a colour or a size depending on the variationtypeid

**so why does this query fail ??**

```
SELECT [t4].[ProductVariationID], [t5].[UKTitle] AS [Size], 
       [t6].[UKTitle] AS [Colour], [t0].[Title]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Product] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_ProductCategory] AS [t1] 
    ON [t0].[ProductID] = [t1].[ProductID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[vw_ProductImage] AS [t2] 
    ON [t0].[ProductID] = [t2].[ProductID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Brand] AS [t3] 
    ON [t0].[BrandID] = [t3].[BrandID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_ProductVariation] AS [t4] 
    ON [t0].[ProductID] = [t4].[ProductID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Variation] AS [t5] 
    ON [t5].[VariationID] = [t4].[VariationID]
LEFT OUTER  JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Variation] AS [t6] 
    ON  [t6].[VariationID] = [t4].[VariationID] 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Category] AS [t7] 
    ON [t1].[CategoryID] = [t7].[CategoryID]
WHERE ([t5].[VariationTypeID] IN(2))
AND ([t6].[VariationTypeID] IN(1))
```

Comment: How does it "fail"? Error message?

Answer (score 2):

If by *fail* you mean that your `left outer join` does not seem to work you could try this query instead.

```
SELECT [t4].[ProductVariationID],
       [t5].[UKTitle] AS [Size],
       [t6].[UKTitle] AS [Colour],
       [t0].[Title]
FROM   [dbo].[tbl_Product] AS [t0]
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_ProductVariation] AS [t4]
         ON [t0].[ProductID] = [t4].[ProductID]
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Variation] AS [t5]
         ON [t5].[VariationID] = [t4].[VariationID] AND
            [t5].VariationTypeID IN(2)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Variation] AS [t6]
         ON [t6].[VariationID] = [t4].[VariationID] AND
            [t6].[VariationTypeID] IN(1)
```

I moved the checks on `VariationTypeID` to the join clause instead. Having them in the where clause makes your outer join's behave like inner joins.

Comment: Thanks it is working better but it only displays the size and not the colour

Comment: @Andy - As you have written your query and structured your data you would get the size and the color on different rows of the result. If you could provide some sample data for the tables and what the expected output should be perhaps I or someone else could change the query so it does what you want.

Comment: that was my worry that its the structure as thats out of my control:(

Comment: @Andy - It is pobably possible to build a query that does what you want. Update the question with some sample data in the tables and the expected output.

Comment: working now see below using an extra join 

select Title, t1.productid, 
t3.UKTitle as Size, 
t3.VariationID, 
t5.UKTitle as Colour 
from tbl_Product t1 inner join tbl_ProductVariation t2 on t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID
inner join tbl_Variation t3 on t2.VariationID = t3.VariationID
inner join tbl_productvariation t4 on t1.productid = t4.productid
inner join tbl_variation t5 on t4.variationid = t5.variationID
where t1.ProductID=13 and t3.variationtypeid =1 and t5.variationtypeid =2